# How to sort arraylist hashmap in Android?

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I have fetch data from website and take that data value into hashmap. I also create dynamic linear layout and display ol hashmap value in it. Now problem comes when I want to display hashmap value by name and data type, how can I do that?

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)


{


        Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        lin = new LinearLayout(this);
        lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_border);

        LinearLayout linbsc = new LinearLayout(this);
        linbsc.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        map.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtbasicname = new TextView(this);
        txtbasicname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));        
        //txtbasicname.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtbasicname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strbasicname =map.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
        txtbasicname.setText(strbasicname);
        linbsc.addView(txtbasicname);


        lin.addView(linbsc);

        LinearLayout linthrd = new LinearLayout(this);
        linthrd.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        map.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtbasicvenuetype = new TextView(this);
        txtbasicvenuetype.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtbasicvenuetype.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        String strbasicvenuetype =map.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
        txtbasicvenuetype.setText(strbasicvenuetype+"-");
        linthrd.addView(txtbasicvenuetype);



        lin.addView(linthrd);

        LinearLayout linforth = new LinearLayout(this);
        linforth.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        map.put("address",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("address").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtbasicaddress = new TextView(this);
        txtbasicaddress.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        txtbasicaddress.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strbasicaddress =map.put("address",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("address").getNodeValue());
        txtbasicaddress.setText(strbasicaddress+",");
        linforth.addView(txtbasicaddress);

        map.put("city",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("city").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtbasiccity = new TextView(this);
        txtbasiccity.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        String strbasiccity =map.put("city",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("city").getNodeValue());
        txtbasiccity.setText(strbasiccity+",");
        linforth.addView(txtbasiccity);


        LinearLayout linfifth = new LinearLayout(this);
        linfifth.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        map.put("zip",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("zip").getNodeValue());
        TextView txtbasiczip = new TextView(this);
        txtbasiczip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        txtbasiczip.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));         
        String strbasiczip =map.put("zip",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("zip").getNodeValue());
        txtbasiczip.setText(strbasiczip+".");
        linfifth.addView(txtbasiczip);  

        lin.addView(linfifth);
        linm.addView(lin);
        dataList.add(map); 
        mylist.add(map);




    }


    System.out.println("data list = "+dataList);
    System.out.println("data list = "+dataListfeture);
```

Comment: Can you put details about your data which you are storing in HashMap in as key and value. like what is key and what datas are value.

Answer (score 1):

you can sort an HashMap easily by using a TreeMap as

```
TreeMap sortedMap1=new TreeMap<String, String>(HashMap Object);
```

The TreeMap automatically sorts the keys So,we can get a sorted keySet() as follows

```
sortedMap1.keySet();
```

Comment: give me some example so i can understands it better way

Answer (score 0):

you can use [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) that will sort data on its key.

[here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/sortedmap.shtml)  is good example take a look.

Comment: ye dude nice tutorial but i want some detail so i can manage it better way give me some hints or complete tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Declare the HashMap like the following and any item added to the map will be automatically sorted:

```
// This will create a map that will order the keys, ignoring casing of the strings
// (The 'String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER' can be removed if not wanted)
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

That means if you do:

```
map.put("Hij", "145");
map.put("Abc", "321");
map.put("def", "123");
```

Then the output would be:

("Abc", "321")
("def", "123")
("Hij", "145")